# Why does saving a pptx to pdf result in an empty page?

Tags: python, pdf, powerpoint

```
powerpoint = win32com.client.Dispatch('PowerPoint.Application')
powerpoint.Visible = True
pdf = powerpoint.Presentation.Open("test2.pptx")
pdf.SaveAs("test2", FileFormat = 32)
pdf.Close()
powerpoint.Quit()
```

I'm trying to use this code, to convert a pptx to PDF. The "test2.pptx" is in the same folder and it's not an empty presentation. I think something wrong with the `.Open` line because when I run the code it opens an empty presentation.

Comment: What happens when you manually open the pptx file and save it as a PDF? Is it also empty?

Comment: No, if I do it manually it does it rigth.

Comment: >> pdf = powerpoint.Presentation.Open("test2.pptx" << Have you tried providing the full path to the PPTX file?  And >> pdf.SaveAs("test2", FileFormat = 32) << You'll need to provide the .PDF extension for the file name.

Comment: I added the .PDF and I provided the full path with 
>> x = os.path.realpath("test2.pptx") <<
but the result is the same.

Comment: I get >>Traceback (most recent call last) in <module> 
pdf = powerpoint.Presentation.Open(x) 
File"path for win32com\client\dynamic.py" line 639, in __getattr__ raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr)) AttributeError: PowerPoint.Application.Presentation << ,maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the problem, here is the working code for it:

```
import win32com.client
import os

x = os.path.realpath("test2.pptx")
y = os.getcwd() + "\\test02.pdf"

powerpoint = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('PowerPoint.Application')
powerpoint.Visible = True
pdf = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(x)
pdf.SaveAs(y, FileFormat = 32)
pdf.Close()
powerpoint.Quit()
```